# Python3 sqlite3 BEGIN IMMEDIATE error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have some code that used to work, but after upgrading to Python 3.6.0 on Windows I am getting errors. I can confirm that the same code works just fine in Python 3.5.2. I narrowed the issue down to the following very simple code in which I am trying to explicitly set a writer lock on the database:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('testDB.db')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> conn.in_transaction
False
>>> cur.execute('BEGIN IMMEDIATE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
```

The same code has no issues with Python 3.5.2:

```
>>> cur.execute('BEGIN IMMEDIATE')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xb710ab60>
```

I tried to use `conn = sqlite3.connect('testDB.db', isolation_level='IMMEDIATE')` without success. Note that I am not doing any transaction such as INSERT or even SELECT.

UPDATE:
I noticed the following on the Python [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions):

"Changed in version 3.6: sqlite3 used to implicitly commit an open transaction before DDL statements. This is no longer the case."

What does this mean and how to fix my code so that I can still explicitly lock the database?

Comment: Is the Python version the same? Anyway, read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions).

Comment: Good catch, on Windows, the python version is 3.6.0 downgraded to 3.5.2 and the code works perfectly. I noticed this in the doc: "Changed in version 3.6: sqlite3 used to implicitly commit an open transaction before DDL statements. This is no longer the case." However, I don't fully understand what this means, nor how to fix it. if I run conn._intransaction it gives me false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Python's automatic transaction handling, leave [`isolation_level`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions) at its default value, or set it to one of the three levels.

If you want to do your own transaction handling, you have to prevent Python from doing its own by setting `isolation_level` to `None`.

Comment: This seems to work. I did not realize that `isolation_level = ''` is not the same as `isolation_level = None`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. It will be fixed in Python 3.6.1: https://bugs.python.org/issue28518

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess there's always a risk in using X.X.0 versions. Should have waited for the service pack :)